# Finding Inverse Laplace Transform $\exp\left(-\sqrt{\frac{s}{a}}\right)$

Tags: laplace-transform

Can somebody help me to find the inverse Laplace transform of 
$$F(s)\exp\left(-\sqrt{\frac{s}{a}}\right)$$ 
or at least 
$$\exp\left(-\sqrt{\frac{s}{a}}\right)?$$

I'll be so grateful.

Answer (score 6):

According to the definition of [Error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), we can find the following strong identity: $$\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{k}{2\sqrt{\pi~t^3}}e^{-k^2/4t}\right)=e^{-k\sqrt{s}},~~k>0$$ It seems that here, we have $$k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let's work with the exponential only first; I will assume that $a>0$ for simplicity.  You can use a contour integration without that substitution as follows by deforming the Bromwich contour about the negative real axis and exploiting a branch cut of $\sqrt{z/a}$ about that axis.  So, consider the integral

$$\oint_C dz \: e^{-\sqrt{z/a}} e^{z t}$$

where $C$ is a keyhole contour about the negative real axis, as pictured below.

[image]

We will define $\text{Arg}{z} \in (-\pi,\pi]$, so the branch is the negative real axis.  There are $6$ pieces to this contour, $C_k$, $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, as follows.

$C_1$ is the contour along the line $z \in [c-i R,c+i R]$ for some large value of $R$.

$C_2$ is the contour along a circular arc of radius $R$ from the top of $C_1$ to just above the negative real axis.

$C_3$ is the contour along a line just above the negative real axis between $[-R, -\epsilon]$ for some small $\epsilon$.

$C_4$ is the contour along a circular arc of radius $\epsilon$ about the origin.

$C_5$ is the contour along a line just below the negative real axis between $[-\epsilon,-R]$.

$C_6$ is the contour along the circular arc of radius $R$ from just below the negative real axis to the bottom of $C_1$.

We will show that the integral along $C_2$,$C_4$, and $C_6$ vanish in the limits of $R \rightarrow \infty$ and $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

On $C_2$, the real part of the argument of the exponential is

$$R t \cos{\theta} - \sqrt{R/a} \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}$$

where $\theta \in [\pi/2,\pi)$.  Clearly, $\cos{\theta} < 0$ and $\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} > 0$, so that the integrand exponentially decays as $R \rightarrow \infty$ and therefore the integral vanishes along $C_2$.

On $C_6$, we have the same thing, but now $\theta \in (-\pi,-\pi/2]$.  This means that, due to the evenness of cosine, the integrand exponentially decays again as $R \rightarrow \infty$ and therefore the integral also vanishes along $C_6$.

On $C_4$, the integral vanishes as $\epsilon$ in the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.  Thus, we are left with the following by Cauchy's integral theorem (i.e., no poles inside $C$):

$$\left [ \int_{C_1} + \int_{C_3} + \int_{C_5}\right] dz \: e^{-\sqrt{z/a}} e^{z t} = 0$$

On $C_3$, we parametrize by $z=e^{i \pi} x$ and the integral along $C_3$ becomes

$$\int_{C_3} dz \: e^{-\sqrt{z/a}} e^{z t} = e^{i \pi} \int_{\infty}^0 dx \: e^{-i \sqrt{x/a}} e^{-x t}$$

On $C_5$, however, we parametrize by $z=e^{-i \pi} x$ and the integral along $C_5$ becomes

$$\int_{C_5} dz \: e^{-\sqrt{z/a}} e^{z t} = e^{-i \pi} \int_0^{\infty} dx \: e^{i \sqrt{x/a}} e^{-x t}$$

We may now write

$$-\frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_0^{\infty} dx \: e^{- x t} \left ( e^{i \sqrt{x/a}} - e^{-i \sqrt{x/a}} \right ) + \frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \: e^{-\sqrt{s/a}} e^{s t} = 0$$

Therefore, the ILT of $\hat{f}(s) = e^{-\sqrt{s/a}}$ is given by

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \: e^{-\sqrt{s/a}} e^{s t} &= \frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_0^{\infty} dx \: e^{- x t} \left ( e^{i \sqrt{x/a}} - e^{-i \sqrt{x/a}} \right )\\ &= \frac{a}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du\: u \,e^{-a t u^2} \sin{u}\end{align}$$

The last step involved substituting $x=a u^2$ and exploiting the evenness of the integrand.  This integral may be evaluated as follows:

$$\begin{align}\frac{a}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du\: u \,e^{-a t u^2} \sin{u} &= \frac{a}{\pi} \Im{\left [\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du\:u\, e^{-a t u^2} e^{i u} \right]}\\ &= \frac{a}{\pi} \Im{\left [\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du\:u\, e^{-a t (u-i/(2 a t))^2} e^{-1/(4 a t)}\right ]}\\ &= \frac{a}{\pi} e^{-1/(4 a t)} \Im{\left [\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv \: \left ( v + \frac{i}{2 a t} \right ) e^{-a t v^2} \right]}\\ &= \frac{a}{\pi} e^{-1/(4 a t)}  \frac{1}{2 a t} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{ at}} \end{align}$$

Therefore the result is that

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}[e^{-\sqrt{z/a}}](t) = \frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} dz \: e^{-\sqrt{z/a}} e^{z t} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi a}} t^{-3/2} e^{-\frac{1}{4 a t}}$$

Now, to get the ILT of $F(s) e^{-\sqrt{z/a}}$, you may use the convolution theorem for Laplace transforms:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}[F(s) e^{-\sqrt{z/a}}](t) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi a}} \int_0^t dt' \, f(t') \, (t-t')^{-3/2}\, e^{-\frac{1}{4 a (t-t')}}$$

where $f$ is the ILT of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+transform&a=%2aC.inverse+laplace+transform-_%2aCalculator.dflt-&f2=exp%28-sqrt%28s%2Fa%29%29&f=InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator.transformfunction_exp%28-sqrt%28s%2Fa%29%29&f3=s&f=InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator.variable1%5Cu005fs&f4=t&f=InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator.variable2%5Cu005ft) is what Wolfram Alpha gives (I couldn't think of a way to do this by hand since inverse Laplace transforms are highly nontrivial). You could then use the convolution theorem for the Laplace transform to write the general expression.

Comment: thank you for your answer. For now, the final answer is so important to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind some of my dirty tricks, I will show you how I would do it... I will denote $\mathscr{L}$ as the Laplace transform from $t\rightarrow s$ and $\mathcal{L}$ will be the Laplace transform from $x$ to $y$.

First, notice, that

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}(s^{-\lambda})=\frac{t^{\lambda-1}}{\Gamma(\lambda)}\tag{1}$$

for any $\lambda>0$. That means, if we are able to expand a function $F(s)$ in terms of $\frac{1}{s}$ when $s\rightarrow\infty$, we can use this formula to find the Taylor series of $f(x)=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}$, if it exists.

Also notice that for the transformation $x\rightarrow y$, for any positive $b$:

$$\mathcal{L}\{e^{-b x}\} = \frac{1}{y+b}\tag{2}$$

The ultimate trick is to write $b=\sqrt{s}$ in $(2)$ to get after inversion

$$\exp\left(-\sqrt\frac{s}{a}\right) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{y+\sqrt{s}}\right\}\bigg{|}_{x=1/\sqrt{a}}$$

Therefore, due to linearity (and ultimate trickery)

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\exp\left(-\sqrt\frac{s}{a}\right)\right\}= \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{y+\sqrt{s}}\right\}\right\}\bigg{|}_{x=1/\sqrt{a}}\tag{3}$$

To find the inner laplace transform, we first find its taylor series at infinity, since

$$\frac{1}{y+\sqrt{s}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{y}{\sqrt{s}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n y^n s^{-n/2}$$

Using $(1)$, we then have

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{y+\sqrt{s}}\right\}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\frac{(-1)^n \left(y\sqrt{t}\right)^n}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}$$

*EDIT:* From now on I will proceed with a newer approach, much shorter and less rigorous, older one is found in the section "Older approach" down below.

Using Legendre duplication formula for gamma function

$$\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4^n}\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)},$$

we get, replacing $n\rightarrow n/2$:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{y+\sqrt{s}}\right\}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-2y\sqrt{t}\right)^n}{n!}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)$$

and since

$$\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right) = \int_0^\infty u^{\frac{n}{2}}e^{-u}\mathrm{d}u = 2\int_0^\infty p^{n+1}e^{-p^2}\mathrm{d}p$$

(where we used substitution $u=p^2$), we get finally

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{2}{y\!+\!\sqrt{s}}\right\}\!=\!\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_0^\infty p  e^{-p^2} e^{-2yp\sqrt{t}} \mathrm{d}p\!=\!\frac{1}{2t\sqrt{\pi t}}\!\int_0^\infty q  e^{-\frac{q^2}{4t}} e^{-yq} \mathrm{d}q = \frac{1}{2t\sqrt{\pi t}} \mathcal{L} \left\{x e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}} \right\} $$

where we have used the substitution $p=\frac{q}{2\sqrt{t}}$. Combining this result with $(3)$ we get

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\exp\left(-\sqrt\frac{s}{a}\right)\right\} = \frac{x}{2 t\sqrt{\pi t}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4t}\right)\bigg{|}_{x=1/\sqrt{a}}.$$

---

*OLDER APPROACH:*

Let us define a function $g(z)$ as
$$g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} z^{n-1}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}\tag{4}$$

Clearly
$$g(0) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1)}=1\tag{5}$$

Clearly, also, $g(z)$ is convergent for all $z$ positive thanks to the Gamma function in the denominator. We have
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{y+\sqrt{s}}\right\}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}-yg(y\sqrt{t})\tag{6}$$

Moreover from $(4)$ and by using $\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)\frac{n-1}{2}$:
$$g'(z) = 2z\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} z^{n-1}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} = 2 z g(z) - \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \tag{7}$$

This is an ordinary differential equation with boundary condition $(5)$. Multiplication with integrating factor $e^{-z^2}$ gives

$$\left(g(z)e^{-z^2}\right)' = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-z^2}$$

the solution for $g(z)$ is then simply, in accordance with $(5)$

$$g(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{z^2}\int_{z}^\infty e^{-w^2} \, \mathrm{d}w = e^{z^2}\operatorname{erfc}(z)$$

Using the L'Hospital's rule, we get
$$g(\infty) = \lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\frac{e^{-z^2}}{2z e^{-z^2}}=0\tag{8}$$

Similarly we would get $$\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} zg(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\tag{9}$$ etc.

In order to invert the Laplace transform, we need to first find the Taylor expansion of $g(z)$ in infinity. Let us denote $r = \frac{1}{z}$, then via chain-rule

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}r}= \frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}z} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}r} = -\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}z}$$

so $(7)$ becomes ($\dot{g}$ denotes a derivative with respect to $r$):
$$-r^2 \dot{g}=\frac{2}{r}g + \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

Let us write (summation from $n=1$ since $(8)$)

$$g(r)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n r^n$$

substititiong into the previous equation, we get relations for $a_n$ coefficients:

$$\begin{align}
a_1&=1\\
a_2&=0\\
a_{n+1}&=-\frac{n}{2} a_{n-1} ,\qquad\qquad n\geq 2 
\end{align}$$

(note that $a_1 = 1$ is equivalent to $(9)$). Using these conditions, we get, finally

$$g(r) = \frac{r}{\sqrt\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (2n-1)!!}{2^n} r^{2n}=\frac{1}{z\sqrt\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (2n-1)!!}{2^n z^{2n}} \tag{10}$$

(which is divergent, but who cares).

Finally, combining $(10)$ with $(6)$ and $(3)$:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\exp\left(-\sqrt\frac{s}{a}\right)\right\}= \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} (2n-1)!!}{2^n y^{2n} t^{n+\frac12}}\right\}\bigg{|}_{x=1/\sqrt{a}}$$

this further simplifies using $(1)$:
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\exp\left(-\sqrt\frac{s}{a}\right)\right\}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^{2n-1}(2n-1)!! }{2^n t^{n} (2n-1)!}\bigg{|}_{x=1/\sqrt{a}}$$

and since $(2n-1)!!/(2n-1)! = 2^{1-n}/(n-1)!$, we get

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\exp\left(-\sqrt\frac{s}{a}\right)\right\}= \frac{x}{2 t\sqrt{\pi t}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{4^n n! t^n }\bigg{|}_{x=1/\sqrt{a}} = \frac{x}{2 t\sqrt{\pi t}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4t}\right)\bigg{|}_{x=1/\sqrt{a}}$$

Q.E.D?